# Does struct tm store time zone information as its data member

Tags: c++, c, ctime, time.h

Consider the following C++ code

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr);
    struct tm local = *std::localtime(&now);
    struct tm gm = *std::gmtime(&now);
    char str[20];
    std::strftime(str, 20, "%Z", &local);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;          // HKT
    std::strftime(str, 20, "%Z", &gm);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;          // UTC

    return 0;
}
```

So stored in `now` is an unambiguous integral value, while `local` and `gm` are `struct tm` that store human-readable date/time information. Then I print out the formatted information (timezone) based only on the `struct tm` objects.

According to the cplusplus [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), the data members of `struct tm` are

```
tm_sec  
tm_min  
tm_hour 
tm_mday 
tm_mon  
tm_year 
tm_wday 
tm_yday 
tm_isdst
```

If that's all that a `struct tm` contains, how does the program know that the timezone information from it? That is, how does it know that the timezone is `HKT` for `local`, and that the timezone is `UTC` for `gm`?

If that's not all that a `struct tm` contains, please explain how it stores timezone information.

*By the way, though the demo code is in C++, I guess this question in essence stands as a legitimate C question as well.*

Comment: `tm` doesn't contain timezone information. `strftime` gets the timezone by behind-the-scenes voodoo. If you want to get the timezone in general, that's a bit of a mess. There is ([currently](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)) no standard way to get a time zone. [Fortunately Howard Hinnant is on that job...](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

Comment: Thank you @user4581301 This partially answers my question. But I still have follow-up questions: given all the information stored in `tm`, how does `strftime` know to respond in different ways to two `struct tm` objects? Unless `tm` contains some information like *this `tm` is created by `localtime`*, *that `tm` is created by `gmtime`*.

Comment: The `tm` struct doesn't store timezone infos, what makes you think it does? The difference is rather in the calls to `gmtime()` and `localtime()`.

Comment: [Man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) covers how timezone info is acquired on a POSIX system. Still looking for how `strftime` tells the suckers apart. Should add that POSIX leaves what happens undefined.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt because strftime() can be passed a struct tm and a %Z format specifier and provide the timezone as an output. I'd like to know how it can manage that too,

Comment: Fails outright with gcc 9.2.0 from MSYS2 under Windows.  Seeing that reminded me that I'd seen non-standard `tm`s with extra info. [Here's one](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html). Note the `const char *tm_zone` member. What platform are you compiling for? Take a look at the `tm` implementation to see if they've extended the structure.

Comment: Here's an example of the extensions in action: https://ideone.com/Tx6FED

Comment: It seems to me that this was a mistake that got locked in. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html contains notes that suggest to me that this can't really be done right or relied on. I'd classify the %Z  specifier as dubious and best not used.

Comment: I won't go as far as do not use, but the lack of portability should be carefully considered before using. Especially considering there are better options coming soon to a chrono library near you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard says in 7.27.1 Components of time:

> The `tm` structure shall contain **at least** the following members, in
>   any order. The semantics of the members and their normal ranges are
>   expressed in the comments.<sup>318)</sup>
>
> ```
> int tm_sec;    // seconds after the minute — [0, 60]
> int tm_min;    // minutes after the hour — [0, 59]
> int tm_hour;   // hours since midnight — [0, 23]
> int tm_mday;   // day of the month — [1, 31]
> int tm_mon;    // months since January — [0, 11]
> int tm_year;   // years since 1900
> int tm_wday;   // days since Sunday — [0, 6]
> int tm_yday;   // days since January 1 — [0, 365]
> int tm_isdst;  // Daylight Saving Time flag
> ```

(emphasis is mine)

That is, implementations are allowed to add additional members to `tm`, as you found with `glibc/time/bits/types/struct_tm.h`.  The POSIX spec has nearly identical wording.

The result is that `%Z` (or even `%z`) can not be considered portable in `strftime`.  The spec for `%Z` reflects this:

> `%Z` is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, *or
>   by no characters if no time zone is determinable.* `[tm_isdst]`

That is, vendors are allowed to throw up their hands and simply say: "no time zone was determinable, so I'm not outputting any characters at all."

My opinion:  The C timing API is a mess.

---

I am attempting to improve things for the upcoming C++20 standard within the `<chrono>` library.

The C++20 spec changes this from "no characters" to an exception being thrown if the `time_zone` abbreviation is not available:

http://eel.is/c++draft/time.format#3

> Unless explicitly requested, the result of formatting a chrono type
>   does not contain time zone abbreviation and time zone offset
>   information. If the information is available, the conversion
>   specifiers `%Z` and `%z` will format this information (respectively).
>   [ *Note:* If the information is not available and a `%Z` or `%z`
>   conversion specifier appears in the *chrono-format-spec*, an exception
>   of type `format_­error` is thrown, as described above. *— end note* ]

Except that the above paragraph is not describing C's `strftime`, but a new `format` function that operates on `std::chrono` types, not `tm`.  Additionally there is a new type:  `std::chrono::zoned_time` (http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.zonedtime) that *always* has the `time_zone` abbreviation (and offset) available and can be formatted with the afore mentioned `format` function.

Example code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    std::cout << format("%Z\n", zoned_time{current_zone(), now});   // HKT (or whatever)
    std::cout << format("%Z\n", zoned_time{"Asia/Hong_Kong", now}); // HKT or HKST
    std::cout << format("%Z\n", zoned_time{"Etc/UTC", now});        // UTC
    std::cout << format("%Z\n", now);                               // UTC
}
```

(Disclaimer:  The final syntax of the formatting string in the `format` function is likely to be slightly different, but the functionality will be there.)

If you would like to experiment with a preview of this library, it is free and open source here:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Some installation is required:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

In this preview, you will need to use the header `"date/tz.h"`, and the contents of the library are in `namespace date` instead of `namespace std::chrono`.

The preview library can be used with C++11 or later.

`zoned_time` is templated on a `std::chrono::duration` which specifies the precision of the time point, and is deduced in the example code above using [C++17's CTAD feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).  If you are using this preview library in C++11 or C++14, the syntax would look more like:

```
cout << format("%Z\n", zoned_time<system_clock::duration>{current_zone(), now});
```

Or there is a non-proposed-for-standardization helper factory function which will do the deduction for you:

```
cout << format("%Z\n", make_zoned(current_zone(), now));
```

(#CTAD_eliminates_factory_functions)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the comments to the question which help pointing to the right direction. I post some of my own research below. I speak based on an [archived repo](https://github.com/lattera/glibc) of GNU C Library that I found on the GitHub. Its version is `2.28.9000`.

In `glibc/time/bits/types/struct_tm.h` there is

```cpp
struct tm
{
  int tm_sec;           /* Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) */
  int tm_min;           /* Minutes. [0-59] */
  int tm_hour;          /* Hours.   [0-23] */
  int tm_mday;          /* Day.     [1-31] */
  int tm_mon;           /* Month.   [0-11] */
  int tm_year;          /* Year - 1900.  */
  int tm_wday;          /* Day of week. [0-6] */
  int tm_yday;          /* Days in year.[0-365] */
  int tm_isdst;         /* DST.     [-1/0/1]*/

# ifdef __USE_MISC
  long int tm_gmtoff;       /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
  const char *tm_zone;      /* Timezone abbreviation.  */
# else
  long int __tm_gmtoff;     /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
  const char *__tm_zone;    /* Timezone abbreviation.  */
# endif
};
```

It seems that `struct tm` does store time zone information, at least in this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons date and time programming is so difficult is that it's fundamentally at least a somewhat difficult problem: "Thirty days hath September", and [sexagesimal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal), and time zones, and daylight saving time, and leap years, and let's not even talk about leap seconds.

But the other reason it's difficult is that all too many libraries and languages make a perfect mess of it, and C is unfortunately no exception.  (C++ is trying to do better, as Howard mentions in his answer.)

Even though everybody knows global variables are Bad, C's date/time functions basically use a couple of them.  In effect, the concept of "this system's current time zone" is a global variable, and the global data which describes that time zone is shared willy-nilly between `localtime` and `strftime` and a number of other functions.

So `strftime` can fill in `%z` and `%Z` based on that global data, even if it isn't passed in as part of a `struct tm` value.

That's obviously a suboptimal arrangement, and it would start causing real problems if there were a way for a program to dynamically *change* the time zone it wants to use for `localtime` and the rest.  (And this arrangement persists in part because there's *not* actually a good, portable, Standard way for a program to change the local time zone it's using.)

Over the years there have been various half-hearted attempt to clean some of the mess up (while preserving backwards compatibility, of course).  One of those attempts involves the extended `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone` fields you've discovered in some systems' versions of `struct tm`.  Those additions are a *huge* improvement -- I can't imagine doing serious date/time programming on a system without them -- but they're still not Standard, and there are still plenty of systems that don't have them (not even with the "hidden" spellings `__tm_gmtoff` and `__tm_zone`).

You can read much more about the sordid history of date/time support in C in this paper: [*Time, Clock, and Calendar Programming In C*](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/), by Eric Raymond.